# How to update value from external JSON in Script

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to use justgauage . I am able to build the page when I hardcode the value but how to get the value from JSON .

```
<style>
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #g1, #g2, #g3 {
    width:200px; height:160px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
  }

  p {
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="g1"></div>
<script src="../raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
<script src="../justgage.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
  $.getJSON("json/test.json",
   function(data) { 
     new JustGage({
      id: "g1", 
      value: document.getElementById.innerHTML = data[0].value, 
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      title: "Production A"

    });
  }
);
});
</script>
```

The problem which I am facing is that I am not able pass the value from JSON.
I am trying to input the value "15" from external JSON.

My JSON is
    {"text":{"total":"15"}}
Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: Pass the value from JSON (I guess you mean JS object) to where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- You need to add jquery before using it in your function, you can add a copy of jquery too instead a web reference-->
<script src="../raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
<script src="../justgage.js"></script>
```

**$.getJSON is a jQuery library function !!**

$.getJSON returns you a javascript object in ASYNC MODE.What does that means :

You need to call what you want inside the function given as first parameter of :

```
var hey = "NOTHING RETRIEVED";
$.getJSON(function(IMPORTANTDATA){
   hey = IMPORTANTDATA.someproperty;// this should be 15
     // ONLY here will be available IMPORTANTDATA that is inside your json file, otherwise the execution will continue with no-sense of your code

    console.log(hey); // Will display 15 in the console
});
alert(hey);// stills alerting NOTHING RETRIEVED
```

Keep in mind too, you need simulate a server in some way because jquery says :

"Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request."

You need at lest a localhost.

so you want probably if the json file have this :

```
{"text":{"total":"15"}}
```

Then the jquery funtions returns a object retrieved from the json file

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("json/test.json", function(data) { 
       //data is an object
       // console.log(data);

     new JustGage({ 
          id: "g1", 
          value: data.text.total, // this will be "15"
          min: 0, 
          max: 30,
           title: "Production A" 
      }); 


    }); 
});
```

Please read more about Handling JSON with javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp), and if that's not the problem, write clearly the question

Comment: This still returns in same issue . The data is not getting loaded from JSON.Do I need to call only this function in script section ?

Comment: mmm, are you testing this in a server ? or local server ? Trying it with local simple files without a server will not work due to some xmlhttprequest restrictions. Remember too $.getJSON is asynchronous. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ . And most important also, did you include jQuery in your document ? all javascript code must be inside the script tag obviously. Updating que answer ...

Comment: I think the issue is happening with function call in the script. I see the error   $(function(){ is not defined .

Comment: Read completely my answer again, and include jQuery library !

Answer (score -2):

to create:

```
var number = {'number':15} // json object
```

to read json:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(number);
alert(obj.number); // will alert number 15
```

for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

Comment: I tried that it didnt work <script>
     $(function(){
      $.getJSON("json/test.json",
       function(data) { 
         new JustGage({
          id: "g1", 
          value: document.getElementById.innerHTML = data[0].value, 
          min: 0,
          max: 30,
          title: "Production A"
     
        });
      }
    );
  });
</script>